# Android studio hot restart/ hot reload does't work

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Whenever i try to click the hot restart button, it says:
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device Mi A3...
Restarted application in 2,534ms.
But nothing seems to change. I was expecting the change of the text of my raised button, but it doesn't show any changes. Hot reload doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set environment variable *NO_PROXY=127.0.0.1*

For more insights, check [Workarounds for common issues](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#hot-reload-not-working)